# three.js: cubemap and renderer.autoclear = false

Tags: javascript, three.js, renderer

I have two scenes which I am rendering separately and overlaying, so have `renderer.autoClear` set to `false`. I am using `renderer.clear()` inside the rendering loop, and all is well:

```
// This works fine!
renderer.clear();
renderer.render( bgScene, bgCamera )
renderer.clearDepth();
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

However, I have now added a cubecamera to the scene, to make a reflective object. Unfortunately, having `renderer.autoClear` set to `false` is causing issues, where the texture of the reflective object isn't clearing when the surroundings change, causing that typical "painting" effect:

```
// Causes "painting" effect
cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );
```

Here is a simplified fiddle that replicates the issue. I haven't included the two scenes, to keep things simple. I am aware that this could actually be a bug in the library, in which case I'll post it up in the repo.

https://jsfiddle.net/pqoz74rf/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by the great WestLangley, over on [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9333). Auto clear must be on when updating the cubemap but can be switched off again for other parts of the render.

```
renderer.autoClear = true;
cubeCamera.updateCubeMap( renderer, scene );

renderer.render( bgScene, bgCamera )
renderer.autoClear = false;

renderer.clearDepth();
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pqoz74rf/6/